# Select missing values pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset where apparently there are no null values:

```
dataset.isnull().sum()
```

```
Patient           0
City              0
DOB               0
Gender            0
Gender_isspace    0
dtype: int64
```

However, if a I do for example:

```
sns.countplot(data=Patients, x='Gender')
```

There are three columns, M, F and another column with no name and at least 25% of the values.

How can I select this missing values? And delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean mask to get 'M', 'F' rows and reverse the mask:

```
df[~dataset['Gender'].isin(['M', 'F'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .dropna() method on a dataframe to remove the rows with NaN values or empty strings.

So basically you can do something like, assuming your dataframe is named Patients

```
Patients.dropna(subset=['M', 'F', 'column3'], inplace=True)
```

You can view the exact column name using:

```
print(Patients)
```

or

```
Patients.head()
```